# Regex extract number from string

Tags: regex

I need to extract the highlighted number from these two strings.

1. Dear IBBL CH Purchased `10.00` BDT at grameenphone.com, BD on 05.09.21 20:06 Card ***9793 Avl Bal: 930.53 BDT Help:16259  Get 10%discount from DARAZ *T&C
2. TK `20,312.84` has been refunded into your A/C **04994509 at 10/01/21 03:27 PM for NPSB Transfer: 71210110003106, Balance:21,019.50. Help:16259,8331090 - IBBL iBanking

I have tried `(?<=tk )(.+\d)` for the first one and `\d.+ (?=bdt)` for the second one, but doesn't work.

Comment: Try `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(?=\s*BDT)|(?<=TK\s)\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*` if you are using the pattern in an environment that fetches the first match. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1nGFWC/1).

Comment: Yeah, I am just matching the first case and it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(?=\s*BDT)|(?<=TK\s)\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1nGFWC/2). *Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[.,]\d+)*` - zero or more occurrences of a dot or comma and then one or more digits
- `(?=\s*BDT)` - a location immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces and then `BDT`
- `|` - or
- `(?<=TK\s)` - a location immediately preceded with `TK` and a whitespace
- `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*` - one or more digits and then zero or more occurrences of a dot or comma and then one or more digits